# Extracting multiple values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple values in rows in a dataframe, which is extracted from a web crawler. Some rows contains multiple values. I want to create a row for each value linked with other data like id.

Orginal data looks like this(printed using df.head().to_dict())

```
{'News_ID': {0: 'gfc_1', 1: 'gfc_2', 2: 'gfc_3', 3: 'gfc_4', 4: 'gfc_5'},
 'twitter_link': {0: "['https://twitter.com/im__samarth/status/1530248663959994369', 'https://twitter.com/mizsayani/status/1530532694685143041']",
  1: "['https://twitter.com/Magaraja2021/status/1714892770593456227', 'https://web.archive.org/web/20231020045756/https://twitter.com/Magaraja2021/status/1714892770593456227','https://twitter.com/youm7/status/901162082376220672']",
  2: '[]',
  3: '[]',
  4: '[]'}}
```

Expected output

```
News_ID, twitter_link
gfc_1, "https://twitter.com/im__samarth/status/1530248663959994369"    
gfc_1, "https://twitter.com/mizsayani/status/1530532694685143041"  
gfc_2, "https://twitter.com/Magaraja2021/status/1714892770593456227"
gf_2, "https://web.archive.org/web/20231020045756/https://twitter.com/Magaraja202/status/1714892770593456227"
gf_2,"'https://twitter.com/youm7/status/901162082376220672"
```

Currently splitting the column using delimiter but for multiple columns, the approach is not good.

Comment: Is the comma after the `links` list intentional? That's making it a tuple containing a list.

Comment: This seems like a case for a simple [`explode`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-to-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe-into-multiple-rows). If not, please provide a meaningful example.

Comment: @Timeless I have updated the question

Comment: But now your expected output doesn't match your input (*which seems to be a json*).

Comment: @Timeless I have updated the both part, sorry

Comment: @Alexandra, it seems that the original `twitter_link` key/column holds *list-like* strings.

Comment: Can you try `from ast import literal_eval;out = df.query("twitter_link!='[]'").assign(twitter_link=df["twitter_link"].apply(literal_eval)).explode("twitter_link")` ?

Comment: @Timeless it gives error ValueError: malformed node or string: nan

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate the `str` as `list` using `ast` and then `explode` the column:

```
import ast

df["twitter_link"] = df["twitter_link"].apply(ast.literal_eval)
df = df.explode("twitter_link")
df = df.explode("links").dropna()

>>> df

  News_ID                                       twitter_link
0   gfc_1  https://twitter.com/im__samarth/status/1530248...
0   gfc_1  https://twitter.com/mizsayani/status/153053269...
1   gfc_2  https://twitter.com/Magaraja2021/status/171489...
1   gfc_2  https://web.archive.org/web/20231020045756/htt...
1   gfc_2  https://twitter.com/youm7/status/9011620823762...
```

Comment: Their problem is in creating the initial df from the `links` list.

Comment: I think OP already has the DataFrame. They mention "have multiple values in rows in a dataframe" and "Currently splitting the column using delimiter"

Comment: I didn't see the `,` at the end, because it was hidden way off screen.

Comment: @not_speshal its working with dummy data but not with actual data,

Comment: @barmar, the commas is there between tiktok and youtube link

Comment: @Alexandra I'm talking about the comma *after* `]`, not the one between the list elements.

Comment: @Barmar not the item in each cell in dataframe is as [a,b,c,d]

Comment: @Alexandra I know. But my question above is about the comma after it. That's preventing `pd.DataFrame()` from putting each list item in its own row.

Comment: @Alexandra - Provide a more representative example then. `df.head().to_dict()`

Comment: @not_speshal I have updated the sample data in question

Comment: @Alexandra - Edited!

Comment: ValueError: malformed node or string on line 1: <ast.Name object at 0x7ce1e9d65a50> I am getting this error

Answer (score 0):

Your data:

> `{'News_ID': {0: 'gfc_1', 1: 'gfc_2', 2: 'gfc_3', 3: 'gfc_4', 4: 'gfc_5'}, 'twitter_link': {0: "['https://twitter.com/im__samarth/status/1530248663959994369', 'https://twitter.com/mizsayani/status/1530532694685143041']", 1: "['https://twitter.com/Magaraja2021/status/1714892770593456227', 'https://web.archive.org/web/20231020045756/https://twitter.com/Magaraja2021/status/1714892770593456227','https://twitter.com/youm7/status/901162082376220672']", 2: '[]', 3: '[]', 4: '[]'}}`

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

df= pd.DataFrame(dd)
d1 = df["News_ID"].reset_index()
display(d1)

df['twitter_link'] = df['twitter_link'].apply(lambda s: list(ast.literal_eval(s)))
d2 = df['twitter_link'].explode().reset_index()
display(d2)

d3 = d2.join(d1, on="index" ,lsuffix='_left', rsuffix='_right')
d3[['News_ID', "twitter_link"]]
```

Results:
[image]

Comment: See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), specifically: "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages". Also the multiple `reset_index` and `join` are unnecessary. OP also doesn't need the `NaN` rows.